# PHP, passing parameters to object method or using instance variables

Tags: php, oop, methods, parameters, instance

This is something I have never been fully sure of or never found a solid answer for.

Lets say I have a User class with a register() method inside it and I'm not sure which way is best to implement this method.

In my register.php page should I have

```
$user->register($_POST['firstName'], $_POST['lastName'], $_POST['username'], etc..);
```

and then in the register() method don't bother setting the objects attributes and just use the variables supplied in the signature of the method or should I do

```
$user->register();
```

and then in the register function do something like

```
$this->firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$this->lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
etc...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering `$_POST` is defined in the global scope, it would make more sense to use your latter approach (not passing in arguments and setting it up from the function). NOTE however, that this will only work in the case that `$_POST` is declared in the global scope (in this case) and you will lose flexibility in scenarios when you pass in the class from external PHP modules.

Comment: Ok cool thanks for the quick reply. I've been using the last approach so looks like I don't have to change any code.

Answer (score 3):

If the register method is tied to the object (the instance, not the class), the I'd have it use the internal properties which have to be set in advance. So, you instantiate a user, set the properties and then call $user->register().

```
$user = new User();
$user->firstName = 'name'; //$user->setFirstName('name') could also work
$user->lastName = 'last name'; // for this to work, the properties have to be public
$user->register();
```

User A should only be able to register itself, and not anything else.

If you use a method with parameters, you could basically register anything (not only a user).

Also, if registration means writing the parameters to a database, a method that only uses the internals of the user object is more robust. If you decide to change the registration mechanism (if you need some other info from the user object), only the user class has to be modified.

Edit:

Now that I've thought about it a bit more, I think I'd make another class to register users, it would take the entire user object and add a role or whatever and save it to the database. That way, a user object is a bit simpler, and does not need to know how it is registered or unregistered, and if the registration mechanism changes, the users can stay the same.

Edit 2:

Be careful when setting object properties from a method that is not a really a setter (like you would in the register($fname, $lname, ...)). The same approach has brought me headaches when "something" would change my object for no apparent reason, and I couldn't find a setter or a direct call to the property anywhere in code.

Comment: When you say instantiate the user, set the properties and then call the $user->register() function, in what way do you mean set the properties? Using a setter method for each property before I run the register() method?

Comment: You don't have to use a setter, you can access the property directly (if it's public). Although, a setter could give you a way of validating the input, you could throw an exception if the last name is empty or something like that. 
I've added code to the post because it's tricky to do it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation is purely up to you. You can do either way. Here is an example:

```
class User{

    protected $_firstName = null;

    protected $_lastName = null;


    public function register( array $params = array() ){
        if(!empty($params) ){
           $this->setParams($params);
        }
        // Do more processing here...
    }


    public function setParams($params){
       // Set each of the users attributes.
    }


    public function setFirstName($name = null){
       if($name !== null){
          $this->_firstName = $name;
          return true;
       }
       return false;
    }


    public function getFirstName(){
       return $this->_firstName;
    }


    // Same getter and setter methods for other attributes...

}
```

This way you can pass an array of User attributes to the `$_POST` or you can do it individually by calling `$user->setFirstName()`, `$user->setLastName()`, etc...